# how to save a many-to-one objects in django 1.9

Tags: django, django-models

I'm new to django and I'm having this error

```
IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: boxes_suggestion.box_id
```

this is my model

```
class Box(models.Model):
    """
    Box model
    """
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)     
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(_('slug'), populate_from="id")
    identify = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Suggestion(models.Model):
    """
    Suggestion model
    """
    def __str__(self):
        return self.content[0:10]

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)     
    box = models.ForeignKey(Box, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
```

A Box(Suggestion box) has many suggestions but when I try to create a Suggestion `s = Suggestion(content=fake.text()).save()`
 I'm getting the error mentionned above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Suggestion.box` is a foreign key to `Box` and cannot be null. When you save a Suggestion object, you must assign it to an already existing Box.

```
test_box = Box.objects.create(title='test box')

# now we can save suggestion
s = Suggestion(box=test_box, content=fake.text())
s.save()
```